# how to reconnect client to different server ip in C without opening new socket

Tags: c, sockets

Is it possible to close an old server ip connection and connect it to a new server ip in a client side socket program using C? I have my client program connected with server over SCTP connection and at certain condition I want to disconnect from an old server and connect to new one without opening a new socket?
Client side code:

```
connSock = socket (AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_SCTP);
if (connSock == -1)
{
      perror("socket()");
      exit(1);
}

struct sctp_paddrparams params;
len = sizeof(params);

memset(&params, 0, sizeof(params));
if (getsockopt(connSock, IPPROTO_SCTP, SCTP_PEER_ADDR_PARAMS, &params, &len)) {
       perror("getsockopt");
       exit(1);
}
        
// set client address
struct sockaddr_in localaddr;
localaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
char* client_ip = get_our_ip();
localaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(client_ip) ;
localaddr.sin_port = 0; 
bind(connSock, (struct sockaddr *)&localaddr, sizeof(localaddr));

// set server address
bzero ((void *) &servaddr, sizeof (servaddr));
servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
servaddr.sin_port = htons (port); 
servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(server_ip); 

ret = connect(connSock, (struct sockaddr *) &servaddr, sizeof (servaddr)); 
if (ret == -1)
{
    perror("connect()");
    close(connSock);
    exit(1);
}


if(due_to_some_condition_got_new_server_ip){
        ------------------------------> I have new server_ip2 to connect 
}
```

Comment: _"I want to disconnect from an old server and connect to new one without opening a new socket"_ - why do you want that? Just `close` and call `socket` again. Done. You could perhaps create the new socket and `dup2` it into the old descriptor if you really need to. I've never tried that though.

Comment: Why is it important that you keep the same socket?  What do you gain?

Comment: @TedLyngmo   i want to avoid unnecessary socket creation overload as changing serving ip would be very often sometime huge

Comment: @ryyker i want to avoid unnecessary socket creation overload as changing serving ip would be very often sometime huge

Comment: @myquest4sh I'm not sure if you can re-`bind` an open `socket` but you must have a lot of  redirections for that to matter anyway. What's going on at the server side? I wouldn't use their services.

Comment: @TedLyngmo "*I'm not sure if you can re-`bind` an open socket*" - no, you cannot. `bind()` will fail with `EINVAL` if the socket is already bound.

Answer (score 7):

It's not possible.

Open a new socket.

Even if it was possible, it wouldn't be faster than opening a new socket. The slow part of connecting a socket is that your computer has to send a packet to the other computer and get a reply back. That happens no matter whether you connect the same socket or a different one.

Comment: I think this should be a comment unless you explain _why_ it's not possible.

Comment: @Roi I'm not sure there is anything to say. It's just not how sockets work. It's like asking whether you can open one file and then write to a different file than the one you opened.

Comment: Well It is indeed simple but as you can see, some others don't get it. `It's just not how sockets work` then explain how sockets work. I honestly don't care about it being an answer but OP needs help understanding sockets.

Comment: @Roi I think even the person asking knows how they work: you create a socket, connect, send and receive, and close when done. They are asking if there's a shortcut to connect without creating a new socket.

Comment: @Roi - Some fundamental reading on sockets, on OPs own time would be a required foundation for understanding. Although it is not prohibited, it is not really in scope for this site to teach fundamentals on any topic. And terse answers, although not an exhaustive treatise on a topic, can be an elegantly stated truth.

Comment: @user253751 *They are asking if there's a shortcut to connect without creating a new socket.* Agreed.  I think the biggest issue is the belief that reusing a socket with the same descriptor value is somehow more efficient, but the actual value of the descriptor is the simplest part of creating a socket ready for use - it's literally just "find lowest unused descriptor value" - everything else still needs to be redone. Edit: now that I'm thinking about it, reusing a socket might be slower - code to do that would likely be more complex and always slower than simple, use-and-close socket code.

Answer (score 1):

With a **1-to-1 style interface** (using `SOCK_STREAM`, as you are), it is not possible to reuse a socket, no.  The socket is associated with only 1 connection, and that connection cannot be changed.  To connect to a new server IP, you must close the old socket and `connect()` a new socket.

With a **1-to-many style interface** (using `SOCK_SEQPACKET`), it is possible to reuse the socket, as you would not be using `connect()` at all, just `sendmsg()` and `recvmsg()`.  So you would just `sendmsg()` to the desired server IP on a per-message basis.  You can use `setsockopt()` to enable the `SCTP_AUTOCLOSE` option to close idle connections that you are not using anymore.

Read the man documentation for more details: https://linux.die.net/man/7/sctp